# ASP.NET MVC5 Image Uploader Create Problem When Form is Posted Using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

When I click on create button every time browse button or image uploader gets highlighted. I don't have validation code for this html element and I don't understand why this happens.

I am using jQuery and Ajax to post this form.
I am using ASP.NET MVC5
This is my model class

```
public partial class tbl_products
{
    public int prod_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string prod_name { get; set; }
    public string prod_image_path { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; } // this is to upload images on project folder
    public tbl_products()
    {
        prod_image_path = "~/Content/Images/choose_image.png";
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    DemoDbEntities db = new DemoDbEntities();
    // GET: Employee
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ViewAllProducts()
    {
        return View(GetAllProducts());
    }
    IEnumerable<tbl_products> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return db.tbl_products.ToList<tbl_products>();
    }
    public ActionResult AddorEdit(int id = 0)
    {
        //create new object of prodocts to pass it to view
        tbl_products prodObj = new tbl_products();//image path set to default image
        return View(prodObj);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddorEdit(tbl_products prodObj)
    {
        //check if the input type=file has image
        if(prodObj.ImageUpload != null)
        {
            string fName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(prodObj.ImageUpload.FileName);
            string fExten = Path.GetExtension(prodObj.ImageUpload.FileName);
            fName = fName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + fExten;
            prodObj.prod_image_path= "~/Content/Images/" + fName;
            //fName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), fName);
            prodObj.ImageUpload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), fName));
        }
       
        db.tbl_products.Add(prodObj);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ViewAllProducts");
    }
}
```

**Below is View**

```html
@model WebApplicationDemo.tbl_products

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddorEdit";
    Layout = null;
}
  

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddorEdit", "Employee", FormMethod.Post,
            new {enctype="multipart/form-data", onSubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.prod_id)
        @*---------------------if no new image is selected then this old will be uploaded again-----*@
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.prod_image_path)

        @*@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.prod_name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.prod_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.prod_name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.prod_image_path, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.prod_image_path)" style="margin:10px"
                     width="200" height="200" id="imagePreview" />
                <input type="file" name="ImageUpload" accept="image/*" 
                       onchange="ShowImagePreview(this, document.getElementById('imagePreview'))" />
                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageUpload, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})*@
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

**Ajax and jQuery**
// method to past form data to controller using ajax
function jQueryAjaxPost(form) {

```
//$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);//to validate form validation
if ($(form).valid())
{
    var ajaxConfig = { // this is a complete objecct
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.action,
        data: new FormData(form),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#viewAllTab').html(response);
        }
    }
    //check if the form has file uploader
    //then set these two attributes to false
    if ($(form).attr('enctype') == "multipart/form-data")
    {
        ajaxConfig["contentType"] = false;
        ajaxConfig["processData"] = false;
    }
    $.ajax(ajaxConfig); // passing object to ajax function
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

}

I am not able to create product with ajax post method.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it in your code, in your view you use `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

If you want to use this, then you should also use it in your controller
or you remove that from your view:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddorEdit(tbl_products prodObj) {
        //check if the input type=file has image
        if (prodObj.ImageUpload != null) {
            string fName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(prodObj.ImageUpload.FileName);
            string fExten = Path.GetExtension(prodObj.ImageUpload.FileName);
            fName = fName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + fExten;
            prodObj.prod_image_path = "~/Content/Images/" + fName;
            //fName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), fName);
            prodObj.ImageUpload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), fName));
        }
    
        db.tbl_products.Add(prodObj);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ViewAllProducts");
      }
    }
```

When you submit form, you sends data to your Controller method. If method has ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute, it validates if data you are sending has your ForgeryToken.